# Unit tests of xcframework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unit-testing, xcframework

I made my xcframework but I can't run its unit-tests on iPhone because:

> Logic Testing Unavailable Logic Testing on iOS devices is not
> supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator.

I found out it means I have to set host app for my xcframework. So I injected the framework into a host app project - just dragged it. And I got a nested structure with two test targets, one for the host app and the other for the framework. The first one is not needed at this point but the second one still doesn't want to run tests because host app isn't set. I managed to do it by setting these fields in Build Settings:

> Test Host: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/HostApp.app/HostApp
>
> Bundle Loader: $(TEST_HOST)

Please note: I did this in the second test target. After that, Xcode allowed the tests to run, but they hang every time they run. And a warning appeared:

> /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/MegaApp/Framework/Framework.xcodeproj Unable to find
> a target which creates the host product for value of $(TEST_HOST)
> '/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HostApp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HostApp.app/HostApp'

This looks like Xcode expects framework's main target to produce the binary of the host app I specified in its test target. But framework's main target does the other work in accordance with its purpose. And I got stuck here.

Anyway, is it something that can be easily fixed or it's impossible to run tests for xcframework on device?